# echo username from session without defining in every controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [echo user in view from sessions code igniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336122/echo-user-in-view-from-sessions-code-igniter)

I don't want to define and store the user in every controller and then pass it to the view.
Here's my controller:

Login controller:

```
class LoginController extends CI_Controller {
    function index(){       
        $new['main_content'] = 'loginView';
        $this->load->view('loginTemplate/template', $new);          
    }

    function verifyUser(){

    //getting parameters from view 
    $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
    );      

    $this->load->model('loginModel'); 
    $query = $this->loginModel->validate($data);

    if ($query){             
        //if the user c validated data variable is created becx we want to put username in session

            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                 'is_logged_in' => true 
            );

           $this->session->set_userdata($data);
           redirect('sessionController/dashboard_area');
    }else{
        $this->index();
    }
}
function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->index();
}
}



?>
```

My controller, which I've stored in core folder, so now every controller now extends this controller. I think this controller can be customize so I can access the user in every view page which extended this controller:

```
   class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
        function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->is_logged_in();

    }   
    function dashboard_area(){
    $data['main_content'] = 'dashboardView';
    $this->load->view('dashboardTemplate/template', $data);         
    }

function is_logged_in()
{
    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

    if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true)
    {
        echo 'You don\'t have permission to access this page.';
        redirect('loginController');
    }
}


           }
?>
```

Here is my simple one member controller which extended the above controller:
Here in index function I am storing the username and then pass into the view which I don't want to do:

```
     class CategoryController extends MY_Controller {
   function index(){         
    $data['main_content'] = 'categoryView';         
    $username= $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data['username']=$username;
    $this->load->view('dashboardTemplate/template',$data);
      }
```

Comment: Isn't this the same question [you asked earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336122/echo-user-in-view-from-sessions-code-igniter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call `$this->session->userdata('username')` in your view.

It is stored in the session, so you do not have to pass it to the views from the controller.

**UPDATE PER COMMENT;**
if you want to load a view depending on the base controller (eg user), I would use a [template library](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/) and set the template to use in the construct of the base controller.

For example (using this [template library](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/));

```
class MY_User extends CI_Controller {
   public __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->is_logged_in();
      $this->template->set_template('user');
   }
}

class MY_Admin extends CI_Controller {
   public __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->is_logged_in();
      $this->template->set_template('admin');
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks thats gud too ..but  what  i want is that what if as i define my own controller called MY_Controller .. so every one who extends this controller is for admin and define another controller which is for users .. so the controller which extends that controller load the users view .. is that possible? ... i dont want to make checks in every where like if user = admin bla bla bla